# OpenGL causes memory leaks

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I have an OpenGL ES activity and for some reason it causes memory leaks even after commenting almost every line. This is the remaining code

The .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface PlayMain : GLKViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>{ }

@end
```

The .m file

```
@interface PlayMain ()
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *effect;

@end

@implementation PlayMain{}

@synthesize context = _context;
@synthesize effect = _effect;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
    if (!self.context)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
}
```

After about 10-20 switches between the openGL activity and another one(it contains 3 labels and one button which creates a segue back to the openGL activity) the app receives a memory warning. If I continue then after a few more switches the process is terminated. Am I missing something?

Also the device on which I am testing is an ipod4 and I am using ARC in the project settings.

Comment: Did you run the memory leaks instrument ? Also notice that memory warnings might be happening from other apps currently running on your device so try closing them as well.

Comment: I runed with the leaks instrument enabled and no leaks were found. When testing I closed all the other open apps so I'm pretty sure that my app is causing the memory leaks

Comment: When switching between opengl and your other activity does viewDidLoad is called again ? (i.e. does you view is deallocated and allocated once activity is restored ?)

Comment: Yes, when switching between activities, the viewDidLoad is called every time.

Comment: Now I know you use ARC but the initialization of the opengl context is quite troubling as it will happen everytime you view is loaded and if you switch rapidly between the activities I think it will be created more than once (until the old ones will be cleaned).

Comment: As it turned out, the issue was caused by bad usage of segues. Instead of using "[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];", I was performing a new segue every time the game went back to the OpenGL activity and as a result the memory kept growing.